# Android Java: change Typeface in Dialog - Class

Tags: java, android, dialog, assets, typeface

I have a `dialog` class where I want to make a **custom** `dialog`

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog{}
```

But now when I want to change the `typeface` of a `textview` in the `dialog` I try:

```
MyTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "xxx.ttf");
```

But `getAssets()` isn't available in a `class` where I extend `dialog`.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Dialog has getContext() method, try getContext().getAssets()

Comment: Post more relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

```
MyTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "xxx.ttf");
```